# When NFC Tag is detected, how does the intent dispatched 

Tags: android, screen, nfc, ndef

I am confused about the method of dispatching intent, such as how ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED Intents can be broadcast?

And the other question is when we lock screen, ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED Intents can not be received, or these intents does not be broadcast?

--now I can see it will be send by dispatchTagInternal()
--comments
  now I do not understand NFC-C polling and NFC-EE routing. what are they reprensent?
then NFC-C polling, is like discover,but what does 'C' mean?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through the excellent description here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

BR
STeN